# Passing/Updating value of variable across multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2, parameter-passing, updating

I'm working on swift. So in my project I have used 7 controllers and a variable, which I have used across all 7 controller. My question is,  how will I change value of my variable(say first controller), such that it automatically gets updated across all the controllers.

What would be the correct way of performing this and how would I go about it??

Answer (score 0):

Create Global variable with singleton shared instance.
[Herer is the link, its a step by step tutorial](http://www.wadecantley.com/lifeblog/2014/11/25/global-variables-singletons-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

**Use Singleton Class**

```
class GlobalObjects {
    static let shared = GlobalObjects()
    fileprivate init() {
    }  
    var MyDetail : User!
}
```

Use:

```
print(GlobalObjects.shared.MyDetail)
```

1. Update values in **viewWillAppear** method by using singleton class variable.

OR

2. Use NotificationCenter, add observer on all of your 7 controllers and post notification to update values

Answer (score -1):

You can use didSet posibility of variables. Something like this

```
var yourVariable: Any? = nil {
    didSet {
          yourActionToUpdateUI()
    }
}
```